# Bash - finding minimum number per line

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to get more familiar with awk statements, especially ones that can be done with just one line. I have a file that looks like this

```
9 5 0 2
8 7 4 3
4 8 2 1
```

I want the output to look like

```
0
3
1
```

Is there a way I can do this with just a one liner using awk? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{min=$1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i < min) min=$i; print min}' file
0
3
1
```

Answer (score 3):

The are languages with built-in "min" functions:

```
ruby -ane 'puts $F.min' file
```

Or available libraries

```
perl -MList::Util=min -lane 'print min @F' file
```

Limiting to shell:

```
min() { printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort -n | head -1; }
while read -a nums; do
    echo $(min "${nums[@]}")
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk, which you'll find in most Linux distributions, has a built-in sort function, `asort`.

```
echo -e "9 5 0 2\n8 7 4 3\n4 8 2 1" | 
    awk '{ split($0,a); asort(a); print a[1]; }'
0
3
1
```